# Add field to a JSON file

Tags: php, json

I have a very simple JSON file "json.txt" :

```
{
"status": true,

"data": 
{
    "clics": 
    [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "title": "Title 1",
            "comment": "Blablabla 1",
            "url": "http://photostodisplay/1.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "Title": "Title 2",
            "comment": "Blablabla 2",
            "url": "http://photostodisplay/2.jpg"
        }
    ]
   }
}
```

and I would like to add data and get the following result :

```
{
"status": true,

"data": 
{
    "clics": 
    [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "title": "Title 1",
            "comment": "Blablabla 1",
            "url": "http://photostodisplay/1.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "Title": "Title 2",
            "comment": "Blablabla 2",
            "url": "http://photostodisplay/2.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "Title": "Title 3",
            "comment": "Blablabla 3",
            "url": "http://photostodisplay/3.jpg"
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

The php code I use return the following error :

**Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /home/XXXX/www/clic/test.php on line 10**

Here is the php code

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
$file = 'json.txt';
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($file));
$newdata = array('id'=>'11', 'title' => 'sfdfsdfqf', 'comment' => 'sfdfwwfwdsdfqf', 'url' => 'sdfqwsfsdqqfqqqsfcq');
$data[] = $newdata;
file_put_contents($file, json_encode($data));
echo OK
?>
```

**EDIT** - Cezary answer gives almost what I need but is not. Here is what I get :

> ```
> {
> ```
>
> "status": true,
>
> "data": {
>
> ```
>   "clics": [
>
>      {
>
>         "id": "1",
>
>         "title": "Title 1",
>
>         "comment": "Blablabla 1",
>
>         "url": "http://photostodisplay/1.jpg"
>
>      },
>
>      {
>
>         "id": "2",
>
>         "Title": "Title 2",
>
>         "comment": "Blablabla 2",
>
>         "url": "http://photostodisplay/2.jpg"
>
>      }
>
>   ]
> ```
>
> },
>
> "0": {
>
> ```
>   "id": "11",
>
>   "title": "sfdfsdfqf",
>
>   "comment": "sfdfwwfwdsdfqf",
>
>   "url": "sdfqwsfsdqqfqqqsfcq"
> ```
>
> }
>
> }

Comment: *shakes magic 8 ball* Reply hazy, try sharing your PHP code

Comment: @Machavity : I was editing my post but you were to quick! :)

Comment: `echo OK` I really hope `OK` is a constant defined somewhere or that'll give you problems... Try `var_dump($data);` before you try to add `$newdata` in. What does that show?

Comment: "echo OK" is just for my debuging part at the moment sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't that be

```
$data["data"]["clics"][]=$newdata;
```

or

```
array_push($data["data"]["clics"],$newdata);
```

Comment: Where did you get `$data['clicks']` from?

Comment: why does this get a downvote?? the above code (and the accepted answer) adds the $newdata to $data, but the sample states it should be added to $data["clics"]... triggerhappy downvoters... sad... SO should do something about that...

Comment: @patrick Thanks! It works! :) I edited like that : $data["data"]["clics"][]=$newdata;

Comment: @patrick this gets a downvote because 1. it does not address the primary issue, which is the fact that without the second argument to the `json_decode` function, OP was working with an object and not an array and 2. because even if OP had been working with an associative array, your answer is not correct because it omits the first `["data"]` in the array.

Comment: Please check the edited question @CezaryWojcik and tell me again I didn't answer the question right... Anyway, this should not have received a downvote. Pozinux, glad I could point you in the right direction!

Answer (score 3):

The issue lies with this bit of code:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($file));
```

This returns an object, not an associative array. Change that line to this:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);
```

The second argument in [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) specifies whether you want an associative array or not, and it defaults to `false`.

**EDIT:**

You're currently adding something to the root array. To add to the `clics` array, you can replace `$data[] = $newdata;` with:

```
$data['data']['clics'][] = $newdata;
```

Comment: Hum... Almost! The result is close to what I want but is not. Here is what I get edited in my post.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your EDIT in time. I found the solution before by modifying Patrick answer. Thanks again!